# Lisp Pretty Print Object on One Line

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, pretty-print, sbcl

I'm writing a list of lists to a .dot file to generate a tree. It seems that the pretty printer in lisp inserts new lines in the output so when I execute the dot file, the new lines make it hard to read the generated graph.

I've looked at the `format` documentation, but I haven't quite been able to make good use of it.

Here is a sample list that should be printed:

```
(((TOWER 'D 'C ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '4 ^TOP '8)
  (TOWER 'C 'B ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '2 ^TOP '6)
  (TOWER 'B 'A ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '0 ^TOP '4) (ON 'D 'C)
  (ON 'C 'B) (ON 'B 'A))
 ((TOWER 'D 'C ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '4 ^TOP '8)
  (TOWER 'C 'B ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '2 ^TOP '6)
  (TOWER 'B 'A ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '0 ^TOP '4) (ON 'D 'C)
  (ON 'C 'B) (ON 'B 'A))
 ((TOWER 'D 'C ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '4 ^TOP '8)
  (TOWER 'C 'B ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '2 ^TOP '6)
  (TOWER 'B 'A ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '0 ^TOP '4) (ON 'D 'C)
  (ON 'C 'B) (ON 'B 'A))
 ((TOWER 'D 'C ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '4 ^TOP '8)
  (TOWER 'C 'B ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '2 ^TOP '6)
  (TOWER 'B 'A ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '0 ^TOP '4) (ON 'D 'C)
  (ON 'C 'B) (ON 'B 'A))
 ((TOWER 'D 'C ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '4 ^TOP '8)
  (TOWER 'C 'B ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '2 ^TOP '6)
  (TOWER 'B 'A ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '0 ^TOP '4) (ON 'D 'C)
  (ON 'C 'B) (ON 'B 'A))
 ((TOWER 'D 'C ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '4 ^TOP '8)
  (TOWER 'C 'B ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '2 ^TOP '6)
  (TOWER 'B 'A ^LEFT '0 ^RIGHT '2 ^BOTTOM '0 ^TOP '4) (ON 'D 'C)
  (ON 'C 'B) (ON 'B 'A)))
```

Here is how the list gets printed to the file:

```
(((TOWER 'D 'C
^LEFT '0
^RIGHT '2
^BOTTOM '4
^TOP '8)
(TOWER 'C 'B
^LEFT '0
^RIGHT '2
^BOTTOM '2
^TOP '6)
(TOWER 'B 'A
^LEFT '0
^RIGHT '2
^BOTTOM '0
^TOP '4)
(ON 'D 'C)
(ON 'C 'B)
(ON 'B 'A))
((TOWER 'D 'C
^LEFT '0
^RIGHT '2
^BOTTOM '4
^TOP '8)
(TOWER 'C 'B
^LEFT '0
^RIGHT '2
^BOTTOM '2
^TOP '6)
(TOWER 'B 'A
^LEFT '0
^RIGHT '2
^BOTTOM '0
^TOP '4)
(ON 'D 'C)
(ON 'C 'B)
(ON 'B 'A))
((TOWER 'D 'C
^LEFT '0
^RIGHT '2
^BOTTOM '4
^TOP '8)
(TOWER 'C 'B
^LEFT '0
^RIGHT '2
^BOTTOM '2
^TOP '6)
(TOWER 'B 'A
^LEFT '0
^RIGHT '2
^BOTTOM '0
...
...
...
```

What `format` directives should use to get the properly formatted output?

Here is the code I'm using

```
(format stream "~A [shape=record, label=\"{~A|~A|~A}\"];~%" a b c d)
```

Comment: You might want to post reproducible test code...

Comment: Does this edition help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set [`*print-right-margin*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_rig.htm) to a very large number, the pretty printer should not insert any newlines.

It defaults to `nil` to mean the width of the device (e.g., your monitor).